# Is it possible to store information on non-instantiated objects in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, instantiation, jquery-data

I'm creating HTML markup in Javascript by concatinating string elements. Something like this:

```
var makeButton = function (el) {
    'use strict';
    var config = el.attr("data-config"),
        dyn = $.parseJSON(config),
        hover = false,
        state = 'up',
        hrf = '',
        ...

  if (dyn.href) {
      hrf = 'href="' + dyn.href + '" ';
  }
  ...

  // when all variables have been set, concat  
  iconspan = dyn.icon ? '<span class="ui-icon ' + icn + icp + ics + '">&nbsp;</span>' : '';
  textspan = '<span class="ui-btn-text">' + txt + '</span>';
  innerspan = '<span class="ui-btn-inner">' + textspan + iconspan + '</span>';
  btn = '<a data-role="button" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ' + hvr + cls + '" ' + data_icp + data_thm + data_min + data_inl + '>' + innerspan + '</a>';
  return btn;
};
```

When all is set, I'm returning the string to the calling function, where it is inserted into other strings being created. I'm wondering if it's at all possible to store any information on what I'm creating. Since I'm not instantiating into jQuery (= `$( btn )`) I can't add any information using something like `data()`.

**Question:**
So if I have a plain "string", what alternatives do I have (if any) to store information on that string?

Comment: WTH is a "*non-instantiated object*"?

Comment: :-) ah well... a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if I have a plain "string", what alternatives do I have (if any) to store information on that string?

None. *primitive values* can have no properties, so you can't store anything *on* them. Either you switch to objects, or you store the information in some other static structure where it is identified by the string value (of course your function would need to return distinctive strings then, and garbage-collection is somewhat complicated).

So you could just use `String` objects wrapping the strings you want to return. They will have the same behaviour in primitive operations (e.g. concatenation) but you can store additional information on them:

```
btn = new String(btn);
btn.data = …;
return btn;
```

Comment: nice. That was more or less what I was looking for but did not know how to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve (it might be worth considering a templating language like [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) or [underscore templates](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2411-Using-Underscore-js-Templates-To-Render-HTML-Partials.htm) instead of concatenating strings), but if you want to create a relationship between two disperate bits of data, then an [Associative Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) should do the job.

```
// Use a JavaScript object as an Associative Array.
dataByButtonMarkupMap = {};

// Build your button markup as before.
btnMarkup = "..."

// Use the markup as a Key in the associative array, don't worry that it's massive, as long
// as it's a string (or can be coerced to one), it can be used as a key.
dataByButtonMarkupMap[btnMarkup] = "some data";

// You can now retrieve that data via the button markup
var myData = dataByButtonMarkupMap[btnMarkup];
```

It might be worth considering refactoring your design so that instead of passing strings around, you return an object which encapsulates both the template string and the data, eg:

```
function makeButton() { 
    // ...

    // Return an object instead of a string so you can encapsualte
    // additional data alongside the template string.
    return {
        template: btn,
        data: "some data"
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Also the only idea I came up with so far. Regarding templating languages: I'm trying find a faster way to build certain elements, if possible in pure Javascript, so I don't really want to add any 3rd party things if possible.

Comment: There are no "associative arrays" in JavaScript. Please do not use that term. (refs: [1](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays#quickIDX9), [2](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/))

Comment: Both of those articles demonstrate that JavaScript does support associative arrays (a data structure where days is mapped to a unique key) , the authors just urge people not to use the Array object for them.